# Could have a view that lists Committed Sites on top?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, area-51, views, commitment-phase

How about a view on Area 51 that list the committed sites on top, then the proposed ones.  I'm thinking the popular view, but maybe a new one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A new tab that sorts by progress?  Then committed sites would show on top, followed by the top sites in definition.

Answer (score 6):

How about a new tab that is exclusive to Committed sites?